# Customize login.ascx / register.ascx / password.ascx for single portal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dotnetnuke

I am using bootstrap 3 in one portal skin, everything looks OK with the exception of standard controls like login / register, which use the DNN default css. There are other portals on the host that require the original layout.

What is the easiest way to alter the HTML of the ascx files for just one portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would avoid developing a new auth provider.

In most cases I have been able to achieve any customisation required by overriding the dnn css to match the the skin/framework used in the portal.

I know its not perfect but it does make the portal easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Good point. I am using the default BootStrap form layout for all the forms of my site. I just would love to present login & registration in the exact same look & feel and that would normally require altering the html and not only the css.

Comment: As in elegant as it is, if you override the dnn classes on the page. You should be able to get the login to look similar to the rest of your site. What I haven't been able to sort though is the responsive side of stuff.

Comment: In the meantime I found out how to correctly implement a custom authentication provider (see http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134678/dotnetnuke-tips-and-tricks-12-creating-your-own-authentication-provider), I first did not follow the instructions thoroughly and therefore failed. However, once I styled my login.ascx the BootStrap way, I of course wanted to get the registration and "lost password" forms done right. And they seem to be even more problematic. Summing up I think you are right, css hacks are the way to go. DNN looks pretty weak here, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to use custom CSS in your skin.css file.

If you are using the same skin across multiple portals, you can put the custom CSS in portal.css.

If you need to rearrange things or add other content to login or registration, you can create custom pages.

Comment: Thanks Joe, yes I need to rearrange things (since BootStrap requires certain html). I think custom pages (e.g. a custom login page with the default provider account login module on it) will only allow adding additional controls - but I have to modify the html in login.ascx. I tried to create a custom authentication provider - with little success (see http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/cid/436467). I find it hard to get information on this, so every hint is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Login/Register is actually a skin object that is inside /admin/skins/ folder inside root directory.

You can simply create a folder called skinobjects and paste that control along with its ascx,ascx.cs and xml file. Adjust the classes and code. Switch to skin and add/adjust registration of  ascx control to point it to your new skin object instead of the one that points to /admin/skins folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that is the "Login" Module that will only display the login / logoff links. The loiin.ascx I am talking about is located in \DesktopModules\AuthenticationServices\DNN. Sadly it seems to require mire than copy & paste to get a new version of it.